# selenium downloads txt file with &gt; and &lt; instead of > and <

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm downloading a text file using selenium (Firefox driver) and it has a mix of HTML and xbrl tags. When I look at the website in Chrome, it normally renders greater than signs and less than signs as `>` and `<` but when I download the txt file using selenium it has `&gt` an `&lt` in place of those elements.

part of actual website rendered in Chrome: [txt in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLEz2.png)

.txt downloaded via selenium:
[txt downloaded via selenium using Firefox driver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOfMX.png)

```
opts = FirefoxOptions()
opts.add_argument("--headless")
browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=opts)

browser.get(txtURL)
with open(downloadedTxtFileName, "w") as f:
    f.write(browser.page_source)
```

Comment: When you download the file manually (not using a script), does it contain the same text? Selenium isn't going to edit the downloaded file.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the text file actually contains symbols like `&gt` and `&lt`.
When you open this file with browser the browser shows you symbols like `<` and `>` instead of the above **actual** textual symbols.
So, Selenium works correct.

Comment: makes sense. so how do I get it to download with the > and < instead of &gt &lt?

Comment: You are downloading the actual file content. This is what written there! What you can do is to change some data in the downloaded file later

Comment: thanks for the response. when i download the txt file on through safari or chrome, it doesn't show the &gt. how would you recommend rendering it with the actual symbol?

Comment: Have you tried to download the text file with safari or chrome and then to open it with notepad++, not with the browser itself? What have you seen there with notepad++ ?

Comment: yes, it does not show the &gt. it shows the actual symbol.

Comment: Well, sounds strange